# Order one array item without breaking its key order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I already saw a lot of questions that ask about the topic but I am unable to solve my problem.

I am fetching an array with menu id items from database and those items can be sometimes be updated.

The array of ids I receive from db is:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(6)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
}
```

And I need id 2 (int) to move into the key position 0 ($sortindex) without breaking the array items order. So the desire result would be:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  int(1)
  [2]=>
  int(6)
}
```

For that I am trying to use usort but without success:

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) use ($sortindex){

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }

    if ($a == $sortindex) {
        return 1;
    }

});
```

This could happen to any other item id. For example I could order id 1 from 0 key position to 2 and the result would be:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(6)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = [1, 6, 2];
array_unshift($array, array_pop($array));
```

Or possibly:

```
$array = [1, 6, 2];
$tmp = array_splice($array, 2, 1);
array_unshift($array, $tmp[0]);
```

You're not really looking for *sorting on values*, you just want to swap indices.
If you want to insert the value somewhere other than the front of the array, splice it back in with [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice).

If you have more keys that you need to change around, then sorting may after all become the simplest solution:

```
uksort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    static $keyOrder = [2 => 0, 0 => 1, 1 => 2];
    return $keyOrder[$b] - $keyOrder[$a];
});
```

Comment: Hello @deceze! Thanks for the quick reply.

I am not been able to put your theory into work.

I think I do not want to just swap the indices.
I want to change the indice vvalue but I do not want to break the order chain in the array.

In the example I gave, I move the last item to the top but it can be any item to any other position. Sometimes it only be necessary to update 1 or 2 items but it can also be update all order of the array and that's why I am a little bit lost.

This sounds pretty easy but I am not finding the solution.

Comment: I'd question why you need to do this in the first place. There's probably something you could be doing in the database to avoid this problem in the first place. Having said that, look at the update.

Comment: This is a result from a REST API call to update/sort a mobile app menu. Basically the ids are update when user moves items around.

Comment: I understand now what you where saying with the array_splice.

           `$index = array_search($id,$data);
            array_splice($data,$index,1);
            array_splice($data,$sortindex,0,$id);`

I was able to achieve what I wanted with this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are seeking [asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) function